# Add a 20px 'buffer' to left side of Firefox viewport

Tags: firefox

This question is not about web design.

I would like to add a 20px buffer to the left side of my Firefox viewport. What I'd like to happen is even when Firefox is full screen, the items never butt up against the left side of my screen, instead they start about 20px in.

For example, instead of seeing:

[image: What I see]

I would like to see (note that the only difference is that there is a 20px padding on the left side, disregard the height of the screen snippet):

[image: What I want to see]

Plugins, editing settings files, etc... are all Ok, however, I would prefer the changes persist through updates.

Thank you.

Comment: You might have to make a plugin yourself to do this. Asking StackOverflow to make a plugin might be beyond the scope of this website, unless someone is feeling very generous. There's likely no firefox setting that accomplishes this. It's just a problem of poor website design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a really simple add-on using [JPM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm) tool where `index.js` will contains just this:

```js
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    // This means all sites
    include: "*", 
    // CSS style attached to loaded HTML pages
    contentStyle: "html { margin-left: 20px !important; }"
});
```

Regards,
Ondřej Doněk